# Github pages redirection the URL is not changing

Tags: dns, github-pages

I purchased a custom domain name, I want now to modify my Github pages website which was accessible with : `https://jeromevdev.github.io/santaclaus_nft/` to be accessible with `https://santaclaus-nft.com`.

What I did :

1. Added a file `CNAME` to my repository which contains `santaclaus-nft.com`
2. Added a redirection on my hosting provider to redirect `https://santaclaus-nft.com` to `https://jeromevdev.github.io/santaclaus_nft/`
3. In my project settings under pages I added `custom domain` and I setted it to : [image] and here is the problem happening.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the `IPv4` addresses for the `A` record to your DNS provider as explained on the [Github Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site#configuring-an-apex-domain) ? When you configure a custom domain with the Github Pages, you need to set a list of `IPv4` addresses such as:

```
185.199.108.153
185.199.109.153
185.199.110.153
185.199.111.153
```

You might also need to add the AAAA records if it's still not working:

```
2606:50c0:8000::153
2606:50c0:8001::153
2606:50c0:8002::153
2606:50c0:8003::153
```

You can also check this post on [Medium](https://hossainkhan.medium.com/using-custom-domain-for-github-pages-86b303d3918a) which explains the necessary steps to configure a custom domain. After you configured your domain, it can take upto 24 hours to propagate.

Comment: Hi, 
thank you for the kind answer I guess I'll have to wait now :)

Comment: The last step was to modify `package.json` since it's a React App ! Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm glad that worked ;)